# Function order in the binary

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I need to control my functions order in the executable.
I know it can be done by the linker option "function order" in visual studio, but it fail with the error:
LNK4037: [function name] does not exist

I believe it because the strange names the cpp compailer gives to the functions, but I can't find the right name to use.

There is another option, pragma alloc_text, but it valid only in c. Not cpp.

Tnx for help :)

Comment: Let the compiler output a linker map. There you will find the mangled names of your functions. Needless to say that it is no good idea in general to rely on a certain order of functions in your executable. What is the reason you think you need that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map files contain *only* decorated names, which can get very uncomfortable if you want to control order among various overloads of the same function name.

There are two other [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw3h504y(VS.80).aspx) ways to view decorated names, and my personal recommendation is by use of [Listing Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6(VS.80).aspx):  Project Property Pages -> C/C++ -> Output Files -> Assembler Output.

The other way is to inspect [dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b06ww5dd(VS.80).aspx) outputs - but personally I try to avoid command line tools where I can.

Comment: You were right. I used dumpbin to see the mangled name, and the problem solved. Tnx